# How do I reverse the modulus operator?

Tags: math

So I have this equation: x % a = b. Values a and b are already known. I want to find the value of x. So, how do I reverse plain modulus? Everything I've found was in the order (a + x) % m = b.
I need to do this for an encryption algorithm. It has a way of knowing what the number is, I just need to separate out the parts of it and this is the only part I haven't reversed.

Comment: Do you want to find any solution or all solutions (there are infinitely many)?

Comment: You can't reverse it in general. For example, suppose a is 5 and b is 0. Then x could be *any* multiple of 5.

Comment: @JonSkeet I  have a way of encoding the value of x into the finished equation. That is not the full equation, only the part I can't figure out how to reverse.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that, but the question *as asked* is impossible: you can't reverse that, as noted by the answer you've accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume x, a, and b are integers, as the other commenters have noted, you cannot find a unique value. In fact, there are an infinite number of x values that will work, namely x = b, x = b + a, x = b + 2 * a, ... or:

`x = b + a*k`, for *any* integer k.

Of course, for an actual java int (or long) there are only a finite set of x values.